Activetab Persmissions Removed but Still Being Flagged Google Chrome Webstore
Need a bit of help, removed all the activetab permissions from manifest.json but it's still getting flagged by asking why I need it:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "MoodMender",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "An extension to lift your mood with happy and motivational content.",
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "48": "icons/icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Retrieve user preferences from storage
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["sadContent", "cheerContent", "motivateContent"], function(data) {
        // Set default search terms if user preferences are not available
        const defaultSearchTerms = {
            sadContent: "happy cat videos",
            cheerContent: "funny comedy sketches",
            motivateContent: "motivational speeches"
        };

        // Bind event listeners to buttons
        document.getElementById("sadButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            const searchQuery = data.sadContent || defaultSearchTerms.sadContent;
            openNewTab(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}`);
        });

        document.getElementById("cheerButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            const searchQuery = data.cheerContent || defaultSearchTerms.cheerContent;
            openNewTab(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}`);
        });

        document.getElementById("motivateButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            const searchQuery = data.motivateContent || defaultSearchTerms.motivateContent;
            openNewTab(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}`);
        });

        document.getElementById("customizeButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            openNewTab(chrome.runtime.getURL("settings.html"));
        });
    });

    // Function to open a new tab
    function openNewTab(url) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: url });
    }
});

Tried removing Activetabs permission and updated on chrome still got rejected. Removed the permission and repackaged as new upload but still has the activetabs permisssion.
